# How to define polymorphic python optional parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optional-parameters

My question relates to how to define an optional parameter which can be of different types (polymorphic).

I was trying to define a wrapper around [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) in python 3.x, and noticed that there is an optional parameter `,[initializer]`. I tried to define the same optional parameter, but don't know how. [Search around](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html) shows that I can generally do something like:

```
def info(object, spacing=10, collapse=1):
```

But in this context, the `initializer` can be many different types with different default values. For example, it can be `0` for addition (as the reduce function) and `""` (empty string) for string concatenation. How should I define this parameter?

Comment: It's not uncommon (but generally ill-advised) to expect and handle different types of argument in Python, e.g. `if type(var) is str: do_stuff`.

Comment: `It's not uncommon (but generally ill-advised) to expect and handle different types of argument in Python`@zamuz Alright. But this is standard python library function (reduce).

Comment: would you please make clear what you are trying to achieve?
The parameter type is determined at runtime (i.e. you never define the parameter type) . It would be quite helpful to see the actual result vs the expected one

Comment: @tinlyx: The pydoc of `functools.reduce` has `reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value`, with `[, initial]` being "placed before the items of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the sequence is empty." The type for `initial` does not modify/control the behavior of `reduce` based on its own contents/type.

Comment: @ProfHase85 As in the OP, I am trying to provide a wrapper of the reduce function.

Comment: @tinlyx: Also, out of curiosity, why do you need a wrapper for a *standard* Python library that's guaranteed to be there for a Python installation?

Comment: @ray. In python3, it's moved to functools, and the behaviors of map, filter etc. changed. I'd like to have a set of wrappers for these to mimic old behavior and without having to import libraries.

Comment: @ray`The type for initial does not modify/control the behavior of reduce based on its own contents/type`. I am not sure I understand you. But at least the value does influence the result of `reduce`. e.g. `functools.reduce ((lambda x,y:x+y), [1,2,3],1)` is different from `functools.reduce ((lambda x,y:x+y), [1,2,3])`.

Comment: @tinlyx: It's different if the sequence is empty, and according to the docs, the difference is simply whether the `initial` value is added to the sequence or not. If I understand you correctly, the `reduce` function is not trying to determine its internal behavior *based on the type* that `initial` happens to be, which is what I think you're trying to do. (It probably just needs to match the "type" of the contents in the sequence.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what about simply?

```
def reduce_wrapper(custom_param, function, iterable, *args):
    # do stuff
    reduce(function, iterable, *args)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, e.g.: `def reduce_(f,xs,init=None): return functools.reduce(f,xs,init)` then `reduce_ ((lambda x,y:x+y), [1,2,3])`. But I got: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'`

Comment: sorry for that. There seems to be a mismatch in the documentation. It seems like initializer is a simple positional argument

Comment: Thanks. This works well. Still curious though, about how a positional argument solved the problem in question inside `functools.reduce`.

Comment: the `reduce` function seems not to be a python function but some strange compiled product. So I did not find the way to get the signature. But if you start playing around with the reduce function, you will see that there is no keyword arguments taken by it (eg you cannot enter something like `reduce(...., initializer=5)` . It means it is a positional argument with no defined value